# Laravel 8 : npm run dev error Unknown option '--hide-modules'

Tags: laravel, web, npm-install, laravel-8, npm-run

I have tried to run `npm run dev` and got this error:

[image]

I've tried:

- `composer update`
- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `npm cache clean`
- `npm install`
- `npm outdated`
- `npm install`
- `npm run dev`

and still didn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it looks like some files got corrupt when you run `npm install`

so I f you confused about some settings,
I suggest you to build new project and run again `npm install && npm run dev`

Answer (score 10):

Please check laravel-mix version and scripts commands in package.json file

for laravel-mix 5.*.*

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
}
```

for laravel-mix 6.*.*

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
```

Comment: laravel-mix version and scripts commands in my package.json file is for laravel-mix 5.*.*

Comment: so what should I do? This not solve anything

Comment: It is correct. Like is in package.json source code from Laravel 8.x https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/package.json

Comment: @gvd but in my case, it didn't solve my error